# Save data in SOAP using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, soap

I want to save data via SOAP web service using jquery ajax but don't know how to start

here's the jquery code

```js
function saveData() {
        var profile = '<Profile><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Smith</LastName></Profile>';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://myurl.com/MyService.asmx/SaveData',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'text/xml',
            data: profile,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    };
```

and here's SOAP method, but I dont know how to get data from jquery post

```html
[WebMethod]
public void SaveData()
{
  // how to get data from jquery ajax post

  // do save Profile
}
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: SaveData method should accept the parameter 'profile'. Try following online example and reply back if you face any issue.

Comment: Many thank, you're right :
[WebMethod]
        public void SaveData(string Profile)
        {
            // parse Profile to XML

            // do save Profile
        }